# Php add duplicate values inside an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which contain multiple values inside it, all i want is to find duplicate items and add the number of times they are inside an array. Here goes an example

```
$someVar = array('John','Nina','Andy','John','Aaron','John','Zack','Kate','Nina');
```

I want my final result to look like

```
John = 3;
Nina = 2;
```

and so on.

EDIT | These values are dynamic i have no idea what these names going to be.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Summarizing a javascript array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11139881/summarizing-a-javascript-array-of-strings)

Comment: I just answered this exact question earlier today. Only difference being that was in JavaScript, but converting it to PHP is trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values) and [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) to achieve this.

```
$result = array_filter( array_count_values( $someVar), function( $el) {
    return $el > 1; 
});
```

`$result` will be an associative array containing the names as keys and the number of times they occur as values, but only if they were duplicated in the `$someVar` array.

[Here is a demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6ckVzX) showing the correct output.

Comment: just checked the demo , it's exactly what i want... thanks a lot

Comment: if have used $el >= 1, so that i can also get those which are only for one time...